# How to rotate video in 90 degrees using AxWindowsMediaPlayer library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-media-player

I need to apply video rotation (0, 90, -90) degrees in windows media player application in c# technology. I am using `AxWindowsMediaPlayer` library to implement video playing along with the properties `Play`, `Pos`, `Stop`, `Next`, `Voliume` control and so on. But I am not getting any properties to rotate the video in 90 degrees or -90 degrees.

How can I implement the video rotation in windows media player application? Any Idea?

Comment: Can you tell me why you cast the question down-vote? I didn't find any solution. so I posted this question. Please let me know who down-voted this and the cause of down-vote too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I could resolved video rotation(in 90 degrees) using **FFmpeg** library. Download latest version of **FFmpeg** zip for windows, extract and keep **FFmpeg** library folder on drive C [NB: Any drive or path can be chosen].

Define a function which takes a `string` parameter named `command`

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute the command and output the result
/// </summary>
private String Command(string command)
{
    int time_out = 6;
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

    psi.FileName = @"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";

    psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    //Do not display windows
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    //Specify command line
    psi.Arguments = command;
    //Start-up
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    //Read output
    string results = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    //WaitForExit needs to be after ReadToEnd
    //(To prevent blocking by parent process and child process)
    p.WaitForExit(time_out * 1000);  //Wait maximum specified milliseconds until process terminates
    if (!p.HasExited) p.Close();
    //Display output result
    return results;
}
```

Then call the function passing cmdArgs like this

```
string inputPath = @"C:\SampleVideo.mp4";
string outputFile = @"C:\SampleVideoOutput.mp4";

string cmdArgs = string.Empty;
cmdArgs = " -i \"" + inputPath + "\" -vf \"transpose=1\" \"" + outputFile + "\"";

Command(cmdArgs);
```

Simple command line command is below -

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" output.mp4
```

transpose = 1 for 90 degrees rotation.

Below transpose parameter can be used:

```
0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90Clockwise
2 = 90CounterClockwise
3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip

Use -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" for 180 degrees.
```

Comment: It is by far an excellent solution, I tried the whole thing and helped very well. Better than software meant for this purpose.